# iPhone browser style doesn't match Chrome simulation

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome

I’m struggling right now.

I’m not sure my preloader display very differently on the iPhone even on Safari or Chrome.

[image]

Note :

I've tried clear cache on iPhone settings already.
It should reproduce all the time at: http://206.189.186.68/

Result :
The font load very differently

## HTML

```
<div class="mobile-loader">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center">
        <div class="row tex-left">
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                <h1 class="ml2 mb-0">The New Protein</h1>
                <h1 class="ml4" style="margin-top: -12px;">Map</h1>
                <h6 class="ml3" style="font-family: futuralilghtdcd;">By OLIVA FOX CABANE</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futuralilghtdcd';
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaDCD-Boo.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaDCD-Boo.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaDCD-Boo.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaDCD-Boo.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaDCD-Boo.svg#Futura DC D Book') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Is it because of the way I declared my font in CSS is not accepting by iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are likely seeing how Safari and Chrome handles fonts that overrides each other. A small cleanup should fix it.

You are declaring `futura` in your headers like so:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
   font-family: 'futura', sans-serif; 
}
```

But you've already declared futura in your body:

```
html,body,button,input,optgroup,select,textarea,.tooltip,.popover {
    font-family: 'futura', sans-serif;
}
```

Normally this is not problematic, but looking at how you are declaring @font-face in your custom.css its likely that the two browsers differ.

If you want to load a specific futura weight like `futuralilghtdcd` I would comment out the headers setup:

```
/* dont need this; */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  /* font-family: 'futura', sans-serif; */
}


/* Apply certain @font-face declaration as low-level as possible */

html,body,button,input,optgroup,select,textarea,.tooltip,.popover {
    font-family: 'futuralilghtdcd', sans-serif;
}

/* Even better */

html, body {
    font-family: 'futuralilghtdcd', sans-serif;
}
```

Also its a good idea to keep using same namespace `font-family: futura` throughout the different font-face declarations:

Here you have two separate names: `futurabold` and `futura`, they can both share the same name, but they can have different `font-weights`. The browser will handle the rest as long as you use `font-weight: bold`, or `<b>` etc.

```
/* current */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futurabold';
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.svg#Futura Cond Extra Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futura';
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.svg#Futura Cond Medium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Better */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futura';
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-ExtBol.svg#Futura Cond Extra Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futura';
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/FuturaCon-Med.svg#Futura Cond Medium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Where you able to reproduce or see my issue ?

Comment: Yes specifically if you follow the 3rd code block about commenting out the h1,h2 etc and apply `futuralilghtdcd ` to the body I got the same font loaded on both browsers.